# Какую базу данных лучше выбрать

Tags: c++, база-данных

Мне нужно создать некий накопитель информаци к которому будет доступ разных приложений .

Планируется сделать базу данных в которую постоянно будут добавляться записи.
Одно, два или же сотня дополнений основного приложения (каждый раз по разному) будут подключаться к этой базе следующим образом:

1) одно основное приложение запускает Lua скрипты которые загружают dll на С++. (Lua - клей между приложением и моими дополнениями к основному приложению)

2) одно из дополнений постоянно обновляет записи в базе

3) Остальные дополнения читают базу через dll для работы с базой (из которого импортирую классы для работы с базой).

По сути для базы как я понимаю это будет выглядеть как доступ к ней множества разных приложений. У меня был скромный опыт работы с базами, по сему прошу совета какую базу данных лучше выбрать ? В базе данных будет мало записей, (не больше 1000 думаю) и несколько таблиц. Но нужно что бы она могла достаточно быстро работать данными не висла и могла бы работать в таком режиме (подключения от разных программ одновременное и вполне вероятно несколько запросов на чтение и добавление данных одновременно).

Comment: Смотрите в сторону SQLite

Comment: @ixSci Это первое что пришло ко мне в голову, однако разве она поддерживает возможность работы с несколькими приложениями одновременно ? Как я понял у нее нету такой возможности, или же я ошибаюсь ?

Comment: [Есть](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5)